# Movie player iOS5 play symbol over view

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have been trying to figure out how to get the "play symbol" on top of my movie view, so that the user just have to press that and the video will start. Anybody know how to implement that?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
//Video player
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.navigationItem.title ofType:@"mov"];

_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: url]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_player];
_player.view.frame = CGRectMake( 350, 200, 400, 400);
[self.view addSubview:_player.view];
}

//Plays the movie once the "Play" button is pressed 
-(IBAction)playMovie
{
[_player play];
}

//Exits fullscreen when movie is finished
- (void) playerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
_player.fullscreen = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create an IBOutlet for your button or you will have to add the play button yourself via code like this... (in order to access it via code.)

```
  // Add play button 
  playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(53, 212, 214, 36)];    
  [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
  [[self view] addSubview:playButton];
```

and once you are done adding the movieplayer to the view.... you need to bring the playbutton to the front like ....

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:playButton];
```

remember this to be done once you have added the movieplayer to the view...

source ... http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html